# Duplicate and append random row in pandas dataframe with new values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that is incomplete and I wish to fill it where needed. Each row has many cells that need to be copied, but some values need to be set to 0 instead. Here consider two entities (`id: [111, 222]`) and different columns, `year`, `type`, `value`, `otherData` and `otherData2`.

Here is the code to generate the original DF and the target dataframe:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
randint10 = [random.randint(1,100) for x in range(10)]
newValues = randint10 + [0, 0]
otherData = ['a word'] * 6 + ['another word'] * 4
otherData2 = [1928] * 6 + [2021] * 4
newOtherData, newOtherData2 = otherData + [otherData[-1]]*2, otherData2 + [otherData2[-1]]*2
original = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['111']*6 +['222']*4, 'year': ['2019', '2020']*5, 'type': ['car']*2 + ['house']*2 + ['travel'] * 2 + ['car']*2 + ['travel'] * 2,
                  'value': randint10, 'otherData': otherData, 'otherData2': otherData2})
target = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['111']*6 +['222']*6, 'year': ['2019', '2020']*6, 'type': ['car']*2 + ['house']*2 + ['travel']*2 + ['car']*2 + ['travel']*2 + ['house']*2,
                  'value': newValues, 'otherData': newOtherData, 'otherData2': newOtherData2})
display(original)
display(target)
```

as you can see in the original dataframe `id 111` has data for car, house and travel for both years 2019 and 2020. `id 222` has data for both years only for car and travel, and house is missing.

```
+----+------+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|    |   id |   year | type   |   value | otherData    |   otherData2 |
|----+------+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------------|
|  0 |  111 |   2019 | car    |      64 | a word       |         1928 |
|  1 |  111 |   2020 | car    |      24 | a word       |         1928 |
|  2 |  111 |   2019 | house  |      46 | a word       |         1928 |
|  3 |  111 |   2020 | house  |      59 | a word       |         1928 |
|  4 |  111 |   2019 | travel |      15 | a word       |         1928 |
|  5 |  111 |   2020 | travel |      61 | a word       |         1928 |
|  6 |  222 |   2019 | car    |      22 | another word |         2021 |
|  7 |  222 |   2020 | car    |       2 | another word |         2021 |
|  8 |  222 |   2019 | travel |      74 | another word |         2021 |
|  9 |  222 |   2020 | travel |      96 | another word |         2021 |
+----+------+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

What I want is to take a random row for `id 222` for each missing `year` (2019 and 2020) and missing `type` (house), copy all columns but set column `value` as 0. So here we would have to add two rows for each missing year (2019 and 2020) where `type = house`, `value = 0`, and the other rows would be the same as any random row for `id 222`. The desired target dataframe would then look like this:

```
+----+------+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------------+
|    |   id |   year | type   |   value | otherData    |   otherData2 |
|----+------+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------------|
|  0 |  111 |   2019 | car    |      64 | a word       |         1928 |
|  1 |  111 |   2020 | car    |      24 | a word       |         1928 |
|  2 |  111 |   2019 | house  |      46 | a word       |         1928 |
|  3 |  111 |   2020 | house  |      59 | a word       |         1928 |
|  4 |  111 |   2019 | travel |      15 | a word       |         1928 |
|  5 |  111 |   2020 | travel |      61 | a word       |         1928 |
|  6 |  222 |   2019 | car    |      22 | another word |         2021 |
|  7 |  222 |   2020 | car    |       2 | another word |         2021 |
|  8 |  222 |   2019 | travel |      74 | another word |         2021 |
|  9 |  222 |   2020 | travel |      96 | another word |         2021 |
| 10 |  222 |   2019 | house  |       0 | another word |         2021 |
| 11 |  222 |   2020 | house  |       0 | another word |         2021 |
+----+------+--------+--------+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Is there any easy to do this? I could just recreate a series by typing out each column and what value I want in them, but that is quite bothersome as there are many columns in the actual dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out something on my own. Doesn't look right but it works:

```
def addMissingRows(original):
    ids = original.id.unique()
    years = original.year.unique()
    types = original.type.unique()
    for currentId in ids:
        idFilter = (original.id == currentId)
        for currentYear in years: 
            yearFilter = (original.year == currentYear)
            currentDf = original[idFilter & yearFilter]
            for type in types:
                if type not in currentDf.type.unique():
                    # duplicate row is created here based on 
                    # filtered version of original df
                    # .sample(1) selects a random row
                    # .squeeze() turns the df into a pd.Series
                    row = currentDf[yearFilter].sample(1).squeeze()
                    row['type'] = type
                    row['value'] = 0
                    original = original.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    return original

target = addMissingRows(original)
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(target, tablefmt='psql'))
```

and the output is then transformed

```
from
+---+-----+------+--------+----+--------------+------+
| 0 | 111 | 2019 | car    | 92 | a word       | 1928 |
| 1 | 111 | 2020 | car    | 28 | a word       | 1928 |
| 2 | 111 | 2019 | house  | 69 | a word       | 1928 |
| 3 | 111 | 2020 | house  | 97 | a word       | 1928 |
| 4 | 111 | 2019 | travel | 66 | a word       | 1928 |
| 5 | 111 | 2020 | travel | 17 | a word       | 1928 |
| 6 | 222 | 2019 | car    |  1 | another word | 2021 |
| 7 | 222 | 2020 | car    | 16 | another word | 2021 |
| 8 | 222 | 2019 | travel | 41 | another word | 2021 |
| 9 | 222 | 2020 | travel | 54 | another word | 2021 |
+---+-----+------+--------+----+--------------+------+

to
+----+-----+------+--------+----+--------------+------+
|  0 | 111 | 2019 | car    | 92 | a word       | 1928 |
|  1 | 111 | 2020 | car    | 28 | a word       | 1928 |
|  2 | 111 | 2019 | house  | 69 | a word       | 1928 |
|  3 | 111 | 2020 | house  | 97 | a word       | 1928 |
|  4 | 111 | 2019 | travel | 66 | a word       | 1928 |
|  5 | 111 | 2020 | travel | 17 | a word       | 1928 |
|  6 | 222 | 2019 | car    |  1 | another word | 2021 |
|  7 | 222 | 2020 | car    | 16 | another word | 2021 |
|  8 | 222 | 2019 | travel | 41 | another word | 2021 |
|  9 | 222 | 2020 | travel | 54 | another word | 2021 |
| 10 | 222 | 2019 | house  |  0 | another word | 2021 |
| 11 | 222 | 2020 | house  |  0 | another word | 2021 |
+----+-----+------+--------+----+--------------+------+
```